# Adding C# preprocesor's directive in command-line building

Tags: visual-studio, command-line

For C++ projects I can do this:

```
SET CL=/DMYDIRECTIVE
devenv.exe MySolution.sln /rebuild
```

What is the C# version ([Visual Studio 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2008)) of this trick?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Build tab in Project Properties

On the command line, `csc /define:MYDIRECTIVE`

Answer (score 1):

The following command lists you the options of the C# compiler

```
csc.exe /?
```

The respective option is

```
/define:<symbol list>   Define conditional compilation symbol(s) (Short form: /d)
```

However, for command-line building a C# project you might prefer MSBuild. With MSBuild, it is probably easiest to create a configuration using Visual Studio's *Configuration Manager* that already defines appropriate conditional compilation symbols. You can then select one of the configurations from the MSBuild command line:

```
MSBuild MySolution.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=ReleaseWithMyDirective
```